# Validar numeros con decimales en HTML5

Tags: html5, validación

Necesito validar un rango del 1 al 10 con decimales  en HTML5, pero no consigo validarlo. Lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="number" name="rango" min="1" max="10" >
```

Comment: oks, dare un ejemplo haber si se entiende. Tengo un input en donde hay que estar escribiendo numeros del 1 al 10  pero con decimales y hacer la validacion que no se pase del numero 10. Ejemplo: 7.8  <---ese seria un dato que hay que capturar que seria la calificacion que le daria al vendedor por su venta.

Comment: Entiendo que entonces habría que tener validado tanto si el número se ingresa con las flechas como si se teclea en el ¿cierto?

Comment: Disculpa no entendi tu comentario, pero lo que yo quiero es validar ingresos de  numeros que no se pasen del numero 10 y que yo pueda ponerle decimales para dar calificaciones a mis proveedores, ejemplo:, 6.8 o 10.0 o 5.5 y asi segun los numeros que ingrese.

Comment: Si si, lo único que yo mencionaba es que asumo que tu validación incluye tanto si los números son ingresados mediante las flechas que tiene dicho input (*al costado derecho*) como si el usuario directamente teclea sobre el

Comment: Pues los numeros son ingresados con el teclado.

Comment: Igual esperaré a checar que dicen los demás pero me parece que con el uso de min y max no lcanzará para el contexto completo de la validación que buscas, entonces hago 2 recomendaciones: el uso de js y de expresiones regulares

Comment: Y si se haria el uso de expresion regular, como se haria.

Answer (score 0):

para validar e incrementar ya sea con las fechas o con el teclado puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
<input type="number" required name="rango" min="0" value="0" step="0.1">
```

Comment: Te agradesco mucha la ayuda pero intento ingresar esta cantidad 8.5 y me sale la advertencia Ingresa un valor valido los valores mas aproximados son 8 y 9. Y luego ingreso el numero 12 y si me lo acepta